# jQuery - how to prevent Mailchimp redirect success page from opening on submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, email, mailchimp

I have a simple Mailchimp form embedded in my site (just an email input and submit button), but I can't figure out how to stop the automatic Mailchimp success page from opening after submit? Is there a jQuery function that will handle this? I'd like a simple "Thank you" message to appear in place of the form after submit.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<div class="newsletter-module" id="mc_embed_signup">
                <a href="#" class="news-show"><p>Join mailing list</p></a>
                <!-- MC SIGNUP FORM -->
                <form class="signup validate" action="mailchimp-link-here" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" onsubmit="return Validate()">
                    <span class="newsletter-input-wrapper mc-field-group">
                        <input class="input-text required email" id="mce-EMAIL" type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
                    </span>
                    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_f2d244c0df42a0431bd08ddea_aeaa9dd034" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
                    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
                    </div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="submit" name="subscribe" value="Sign Up" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
                    </label>
                    <div id="success-msg"><p>Thank you!</p></div>
                </form>
            </div> <!-- .newsletter-module -->
```

jQuery

```
$(".news-show").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).next(".signup").show();
    });

    $(function(){
      $("#success-msg").hide();
      $(".button").on("click", function(){
          $("#success-msg").show();
      });
    });
```

Comment: You would need to implement mailchimp sdk on your server and make ajax request to script running that sdk.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$email[0].checkValidity()) {
      return;
    }

    $email.prop('disabled', true);
    $("input[type='submit']", $el).prop('disabled', true);
    return $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: $el.attr("action").replace('/post', '/post-json'),
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      jsonp: "c",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      error: function(error) {},
      success: function(data) {
        if ((data.result === "success") ||
          (data.msg && data.msg.indexOf("already subscribed") >= 0) ||
          (data.msg && data.msg.indexOf("too many recent signup requests") >= 0)
        ) {
          $el.html('thank you!');
          setTimeout(function() {
            $el.fadeOut(500);
          }, 2000);
          $(".news-show").delay(3000).fadeIn(500);
        } else {
          $email.prop('disabled', false);
          ("input[type='submit']", $el).prop('disabled', false);
        }
      }
    });
    });
```